# Handling Display URLs and actual URLs with Linkify

Tags: android, linkify

I am trying to find the best way to implement the following:

- A normal URL would look like
  `https://www.google.com/something/somethingmore/a_lot_more_stuff.html`
- I'd like to display this as `google.com/...` in my TextView (for better readability)
- When user clicks on `google.com/...` in the TextView, the actual long
  URL should be used automatically for further action

Assuming that I have both the display URL as well as the actual URL with me, how can I use Linkify (or any other technique) to ensure that a very long URL can be displayed in a short fashion, yet when the user clicks on the Linkified URL, the actual long URL is used?

Comment: AFAIK, `Linkify` cannot handle this, as it does not transform the original text. `Linkify` handles the reverse scenario, where you want to change the URL. You will probably have to set up your own `URLSpan` objects to accomplish your objective.